# SpriteKit Event-Triggered Method Randomly Stops Being Called

Tags: ios, debugging, events, sprite-kit

So I've been developing with a company's private SDK recently, and basically their SDK acts as another "input" form for the user. I'm using SpriteKit and their SDK (for the input) to make a game, but there's one last bug preventing me from finishing.

The event-triggered method (called every time input occurs) just stops being called at random times, even when there is valid input. I don't think the fault is with the SDK, since I've seen many examples of it working fine. I've ran the allocation instrument during debugging, and the bug occurs even when no major allocations are occurring. I'm posting here to ask for advice not necessarily on how to fix the bug, but on how to debug it, since obviously not much information about the SDK can be given here.

This might be a problem with SpriteKit and/or how I'm using SpriteKite. Any help/advice is much appreciated.

Also please comment if you need more information. I'm very confused about this bug so I don't know what other information I could give that'd be useful.

MyScene.h

```
@interface MCGMyScene : SKScene <sdkDelegate, UIAccelerometerDelegate>

//properties and methods...

@end
```

MyScene.m

```
- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        //initialization...

        //set "self as the delegate for the SDK
    }
    return self;
}

// This method is triggered purely by the SDK, whenever it registers input
- (void)SDKInputUpdate:(int)x
{
    [player updatePlayerWithInput:x];

    // for debugging I've put in basic code here to track when the method stops being called
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you got to post the code if you want an answer. You didn't even say what "event-triggered" means in this context and how that translates to actual code.

Comment: so that private SDK does it come with source code? The way you've set it up if SDKInputUpdate stops being called it's because the SDK doesn't call it anymore for whatever reason. Without seeing or knowing how the SDK generates input it's impossible for anyone not having access to your project to make any reasonably helpful suggestions.